# Twenty ten or Twenty eleven as base for responsive child theme

Tags: child-theme, theme-twenty-eleven, theme-twenty-ten, responsive

I'm about to make a new child theme and really would like to learn a bit about making it responsive. The design/changes will be rather small.

I've done some child themes for both Twenty ten and Twenty eleven but not sure which one to choose for trying to learn responsive design. You could argue Twenty eleven is the latest but I've read somewhere Twenty ten is better maintained.

I know there are many barebones/frameworks, but these two I know quite well.

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Care to cite a source for Twenty Ten being "better maintained?"

Comment: Just read somewhere but can't remember. Doesn't have to be true either.

Comment: It's not. Go with the latest.

Comment: Twenty Ten will be about as well maintained as Kubrick is - that is to say, not at all.

Comment: comes from: http://wpcandy.com/reports/twenty-twelve-theme-talks-begin

Comment: Well, Kubrick is like 7 years old know. That was a totally different time back then.

Comment: There's nothing in that WPCandy link that indicates that Twenty Ten is no longer being maintained.

Comment: no but "possibly Twenty Ten as it’s more maintained and popular" :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both Twenty Ten and Twenty Eleven are being maintained, since both are still bundled with core. However, Twenty Eleven has newer functionality, and a better overall codebase.

I would recommend using Twenty Eleven. The only reason to use Twenty Ten, really, is that the codebase is considerably more simple.

Note: when Twenty Twelve comes out, I would recommend using it. It will focus more on simplicity, and will have some responsiveness baked in.